# Shorten url function, requires two ajax requests to return shortned url string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Using the Laravel framework, I made a few functions to generate shortened urls, the function works (almost), I have to do the ajax call twice to return the shortened url.

First ajax call receives a 500 error.

[image]

And here's the successful call the second time:

[image]

I'm confused how a function can work (but not really) at the same time.

EDIT (additional info):

/shorten is used for routing:

```
Route::post('/shorten', array('uses' => 'UrlController@shorten'));
```

functions:

Which further calls the shorten function in the UrlController:

```
public function shorten(){

    header('Content-type: text/plain');

    $long_url = $_POST['url'];
    $link = Link::checkOrShorten($long_url);

    return $link->short_url;
}
```

Ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $('#litlingit').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { url: $('input[name="long_url"]').val() },
        dataType: "text",
        url: "/shorten"
      }).done(function( data ){
        $('input[name="long_url"]').val('http://litl.it/'+data);
      });
  });
});
```

Module:

```
public static function checkOrShorten($long_url)
{

    $link = new Link;
    $link->users_id = NULL;

    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $link->users_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }

    $link->long_url = $long_url;
    $query = DB::select("select short_url from links where long_url = '$long_url'");
    if ($query) 
    {
        foreach ($query as $links)
        {
            $link->short_url = $links->short_url;
        }   
        $url_id = DB::select("select id from links where long_url = '$long_url'");
        DB::table('users_links')->insert(array('link_id' => $url_id[0]->id, 'user_id' => $link->users_id, 'privacy' => 0));
    }

    while(is_null($link->short_url)) 
    {
        $link->short_url = str_random(4);
        $query = DB::select("select short_url from links where short_url = '". $link->short_url ."'"); 

        if(!$query)
        {
            $link->save();
            $url_id = DB::select("select id from links where short_url = '$link->short_url'");
            DB::table('users_links')->insert(array('link_id' => $url_id, 'user_id' => $link->users_id, 'privacy' => 0));
        }
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: Laravel may be doing something with the post information.  Instead of `$long_url = $_POST['url'];` try `$long_url = Input::get('url');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shortener is working well, but in your first request an exception is being raised in Laravel:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given","file":"\/var\/www\/litl.it\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Query\/Builder.php","line":1407}}
```

This error returns as a 500 error to javascript, that's normal.

But it creates the shortened url anyway, so in the second request it just returns the value you already have in database.

You should have information (call stack) about this in your Laravel log, run

```
php artisan tail
```

And try to shorten another one. As your site is live, I was able to do some tests online using [Postman Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en): http://puu.sh/7IfXJ.png.

You might have a problem with this part of your code:

```
    if(!$query)
    {
        $link->save();
        $url_id = DB::select("select id from links where short_url = '$link->short_url'");
        DB::table('users_links')->insert(array('link_id' => $url_id, 'user_id' => $link->users_id, 'privacy' => 0));
    }
```

You are looking for a link as soon as you saved it in database and sometimes you might get a null, but, since you are saving it and Laravel tries to get the id back into your model, I think you can change it to:

```
    if(!$query)
    {
        $link->save();

        DB::table('users_links')->insert(array('link_id' => $link->id, 'user_id' => $link->users_id, 'privacy' => 0));
    }
```

Comment: Just edited to try to provide some light to the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using `$.ajax()` in the wrong way. The callback for a successful response is put the in the `success` argument of the function, not by chaining `.done()` to its tail.

Also learn to use the `.on()` binding function instead of the default named event binder. jQuery is smart though, and automatically converts it to `.on()` behind-the-scenes.

Try this rewrite of your code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#litlingit', function() {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: 'url=' + $('input[name="long_url"]').val(),
            url: '/shorten',
            success: function(response) {
               $('input[name="long_url"]').val('http://litl.it/' + response);
            }
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks silkfire, I gave the code a try and the same issue occurs.  Any further ideas on the issue?

Comment: @samayres1992 It's most probably a server side issue. Can you comment your code and just return some fixed string in your /shorten page?